# JLabel lost in Java Swing NetBeans

Tags: java, swing

I can't find `Jlabel` in my Java *Swing* palette. I have searched but it isn't showing. Can someone tell me the solution? I'll be really thankful.

I just want a solution to get that key back. I am stuck in my project just because of it.

Comment: Have considered building the GUI without the GUI builder? That will usually result in better code and better understanding how swing works.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post a screen capture of your NetBeans and indicate where you think `JLabel` should be. What NetBeans version are you using? What Java version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following options:

- you can refresh the palette
- you can also reset it
- But if you are facing a lot of difficulties you can just reinstall the IDE